# MySQL joins count matched record from another table but I need ZERO values also

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

My query's aim is: with 1 query get columns from articles table plus number of the comments written for each article. (I have a seperate comments table, both tables are My_ISAM) If any article has no comments then it should be counted as zero also.

converting the accepted answer parameters to my need from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730288/mysql-joins-count-matched-record-from-another-table) on SO, I arrived the solution below:

My insufficient query is:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.title, count(*) AS `count_of_comments` 
FROM articles t1 
JOIN comments t2 ON t1.id = t2.commented_article_id 
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.title 
LIMIT 0,30
```

this query gives me 2 result rows however I have 3 articles and I need to get all of them. (1 article has no comments)

Is my requirement achievable with the editing the query above, if yes can you help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `left join` and count the matches:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.title, count(t2.commented_article_id) AS `count_of_comments` 
FROM articles t1 LEFT JOIN
     comments t2
     ON t1.id = t2.commented_article_id 
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.title 
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Comment: Gordon, I use your approach on 2 tables I have - and get 0 value counts. Until I add a WHERE clause to limit the query (before the GROUP BY) - then I only get a list with at least 1 count. Any idea why?

Comment: @user3741598 . . . Yes.  This is because of the `limit` clause.  Remove the `limit` and you will see the full set of results.

Comment: Gordon, I ended up switching to count(if('where conditions here', 1, NULL)) and achieved my needed output with 0 values.